# What is the difference between linux-next and linux-net-history git repositories?

Tags: git, linux-kernel

git.kernel.org has a repository named [linux-next](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git;a=summary) and a repository named [linux-next-history](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next-history.git;a=summary). How do these repositories differ in content, purpose, day to day usage, etc?

Comment: Your question is not really specific. For example the etc. is a sign that you want some kind of general information, however you have not even told what *your* "day to day usage" is. I mean obviously, you can use the git application with *both* repositories and they don't differ technically, so what exactly do you want to learn about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this explains the reason https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/8/2/95:

> ```
> Date      Tue, 2 Aug 2011 20:08:34 +1000
> From      Stephen Rothwell <>
> Subject   linux-next changes
>
> Hi all,
>
> Noone seems to have noticed, but I have mode the following changes to the
> linux-next repository on git.kernel.org:
>
> git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git now
> contains just the last 90 (or so) linux-next trees.  I have removed the
> "history" branch from this tree as it was serving no real purpose.  You
> can fetch a particular tree by using its name as a tag.  It is now aonly
> about 40MB relative to Linus' tree (as opposed to 300M for the complete
> tree.
>
> I have put the old tree into
> git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next-history.git
> which I will keep maintaining with the new trees, but is just there for
> historical purposes.  It also no longer has the "history" branch.
>
> If anyone had a tree left over that referenced linux-next through an
> alternate, then you should probably change that to reference
> linux-next-history until you have fixed it to not reference it at all.  
> -- 
> Cheers,  
> Stephen Rothwell                    sfr@canb.auug.org.au  
> [unhandled content-type:application/pgp-signature]
> ```